tuples no funcionan en vscode
cuando intento compilar este código en vscode me da error,
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef tuple<int, int, int> TipoXYZ;

error: no template named 'tuple' typedef tuple<int, int, int> TipoXYZ;
intenté cambiar cppbuild pero no lo encontré y no entiendo por qué no lo reconoce :(
puse el using namespace std porque creí que tal vez así se arreglaría, pero es lo mismo. ¿alguien sabe qué puedo hacer?

¿Si quieres crear un objeto o definir una nuevo tipo?. Para crear un objeto sería tuple<int, int, int> TipoXYZ; (sin typedef)

Habría que ver qué compilador tienes, la versión y cómo estás compilando el programa.

Lo mas probable es que estés usando una version de c++ previa a la introducción de tuple.  Deberías precisar el compilador que usas y el contenido del .vscode/tasks.json de tu proyecto. La version de c++ se especifica generalmente en los args de los tasks shell y cppbuild en el mencionado archivo.

En tio el código compila perfectamente. Asegúrate de que estés usando un compilador de C++. Recuerda que algunos compiladores como GCC distinguen entre C y C++; para compilar código C utilizas gcc y g++ para C++.
Además, las tuplas fueron introducidas en C++11 así que verifica que estás usando esa versión o una más moderna. En GCC puedes especificarlo mediante -std=c++11.

cambié el c++ predeterminado a c++23, pero no se por qué sigue compilando como una version anterior y no se que hacer
